# is it very bad practice using !! in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

Recently had some discussion about whether the !! should be used in kotlin code. One opinion is it should not be used at all, because it is a bad practice with kotlin and increase the risk of crash.

Another opinion feels using !! is not a absolutely bad thing, as long as you know that nullable data should not be null at the place under any known condition, !! is just a safety guard there (if it is unexpectedly become null at where it should not be the !! will caught it and raise concern then it definitely needs to be investigated). It should not consider using !! is one cause of crash.

Does anyone have opinion against or vor using the !! (not blindly use it)?

two samples below, dont see the dataCount_2 would be better, or?

```
var data: List<Data>? = null  // it will be set before calling the two dataCount()

fun dataCount_1() : Int {
    return if (data!=null && data!!.isNotEmpty())  data!![0].count else 0
}

fun dataCount_2() : Int {

    data?.let { dataList ->
        if (dataList.isNotEmpty()) {
            return dataList[0].count ?: 0
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: I agree with the second statement, the first statement is just overly paranoid in a good way. Imagine you are extending a framework that gives a nullable value but you design your subclass to not return a null value and then you mention in your documentation that it is not nullable so the use of `!!` is not a bad thing.

Comment: `!!` is useful when you are 100% percent sure that your nullable variable will NEVER be null at that time. However, it can also symbolize that you should be smarter about things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, there are multiple idiomatic ways to express the idea without using `!!`, so it's definitely preferable to not use it. Here's what I would do (using the [orEmpty](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/or-empty.html) function added in Kotlin 1.3):

```
fun dataCount() = data.orEmpty().firstOrNull()?.count ?: 0
```

In other cases, it may not be as easy, so there is no absolute rule saying that !! must never be used. However, in our experience, a significant percentage of uses of !! in IntelliJ and Kotlin codebases end up being reported as runtime exceptions from our users.

Comment: `orEmpty` does not create an empty array, it returns a singleton empty instance. In this case, the use of !! is simply not idiomatic, regardless of the fact that it will never cause a runtime exception.

Comment: thanks @yole! will the orEmpty() create an empty array a bit waste comparing the if (data != null && data!!.isNotEmpty() ) ? I guess the use of !! end up causing runtime exception is the case of abuse the !! (not used in the place it will NEVER be null).

Comment: Is there anything against `data?.firstOrNull()?.count ?: 0`? This was my first idea in this case.

Comment: maybe this post is indirectly talking about the use of !! as well:  http://beust.com/weblog/2016/01/14/a-close-look-at-kotlins-let/,  and isnt !! similar   with the ASSERT in java?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any `!!` are needed in `dataCount_1()`, as after the explicit null check, the compiler knows `data` can't be null and smart-casts to a non-nullable type.

So while there are a very few cases where `!!` might be appropriate, I don't think this is one of them!

(Also, there are two further changes you might make in this case: use a `lateinit` var, which again wouldn't need any `!!`; and replace the whole condition with the more concise `.isNotNullOrEmpty()`.)

In general, my experience suggests that *most* of the time you reach for `!!`, there's a better approach.  But I wouldn't ban it completely: if you've carefully considered all the alternatives and still think that `!!` is the clearest and safest way, then go ahead.

Comment: Actually, it is a mutable field variable, so compiler will say it is not guaranteed to be non-null.

Answer (score 3):

Actually in this case, the simplest and safest way would be to do it like this:

```
var data: List<Data>? = null  // it will be set before calling the two dataCount()

fun dataCount() : Int {
    val data = data
    return when {
        data == null || data.isEmpty() -> 0
        else -> data[0].count
    }
}
```

although I'd personally just use `run` to make it into a single-line function.

```
fun dataCount() : Int = run {
    val data = data
    when {
        data == null || data.isEmpty() -> 0
        else -> data[0].count
    }
}
```

But that might be just me.

Either way, if you assign the mutable variable to a `val` (or keep it in a closure as you do with `?.let {` in your second example), then you can leverage smart-casting and you won't need to use `!!`.

Comment: Actually that just means I'm missing a `?: 0`, thanks -- although that looks messy dangling there so I'll just rewrite it to a different expression

Comment: thanks @EpicPandaForce!,  any comment on whether should use !! or should absolutely  try to find solution without using !!?

Comment: I think you generally should try to find a solution without `!!`, in fact if you need too many of them you might want to consider changing your design (f.ex replace a mutable var with Observer pattern; or just disallowing a null list in this case if possible)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use `requireNotNull()`. Throws `IllegalStateException` if the argument is `null`.